# MySQL + Python:Using auto increment primary key

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table inside my data base as below that I'm trying to insert data into;

```
CREATE TABLE student (
student_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name varchar (20) NOT NULL,
last_name varchar (20) NOT NULL,
year_began int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
```

Using python what needs to be added to the below code to get the auto incrementing primary key working for each new entry?

```
cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO student (first_name, last_name, year_began) VALUES ('{}','{}','{}');".format(first_name, last_name, year_began))
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Apologies if this seems straight forward....newbie at this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When the primary key is set to autoincrement at table creation, when making insertions you do not need to enter the id as a parameter. For me your code is correct.

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat once I dropped the initial data I had in the database.  Next question how do I get the student_id value to display in the following:
``` return success('newstudent', "{} {} was successfully added.  Their Student ID number is XX".format(first_name, last_name))```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3schools.com/python/showpython.asp?filename=demo_mysql_primary_key

this might help..  You need to add the primary key attribute

Either on table creation or try executing after...

is the data already in the database and you want to add keys to existing data or data you will eventually add?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python.
But,you can try this.

```
print "ID of last record is ", int(cursor.lastrowid) 
print "ID of inserted record is ", int(conn.insert_id())
```

the code must in front of mydb.commit()